# Get data from NetCDF to CSV

Tags: netcdf, climate-data-operators

I have a NetCDF file I want to get the data into the CSV file. I am using the following command.

```
cdo outputtab,date,lon,lat,value era_temperature_2016.nc > test_2016.csv
```

I am getting the following output

```
#      date    lon    lat    value 
     2016-01-01 72.9313 33.6871 286.3865 
     2016-01-01 72.9313 33.6871 287.8337 
     2016-02-01 72.9313 33.6871 289.5742 
     2016-02-01 72.9313 33.6871 291.0781 
     2016-03-01 72.9313 33.6871 292.2905 
     2016-03-01 72.9313 33.6871 293.7372 
     2016-04-01 72.9313 33.6871  296.703 
     2016-04-01 72.9313 33.6871  298.181 
     2016-05-01 72.9313 33.6871 303.2804 
     2016-05-01 72.9313 33.6871 304.7249 
     2016-06-01 72.9313 33.6871 304.5008 
     2016-06-01 72.9313 33.6871 305.9426 
     2016-07-01 72.9313 33.6871 301.9163 
     2016-07-01 72.9313 33.6871 303.3689 
     2016-08-01 72.9313 33.6871 301.4589 
     2016-08-01 72.9313 33.6871 302.9072 
     2016-09-01 72.9313 33.6871 301.5118 
     2016-09-01 72.9313 33.6871 302.9666 
     2016-10-01 72.9313 33.6871 300.3135 
     2016-10-01 72.9313 33.6871 301.8115 
     2016-11-01 72.9313 33.6871 294.0796 
     2016-11-01 72.9313 33.6871 295.5635 
     2016-12-01 72.9313 33.6871 290.7698 
     2016-12-01 72.9313 33.6871 292.2829 
    cdo    outputtab: Processed 24 values from 1 variable over 12 timesteps [0.01s 44MB].
```

when I run the following command

```
cdo infon era_temperature_2016.nc
```

I get the following output

```
-1 :       Date     Time   Level Gridsize    Miss :     Minimum        Mean     Maximum : Parameter name
     1 : 2016-01-01 00:00:00     975     3795       0 :      279.24      288.05      294.10 : t             
     2 : 2016-01-01 00:00:00    1000     3795       0 :      281.57      289.20      294.85 : t             
     3 : 2016-02-01 00:00:00     975     3795       0 :      280.10      289.55      296.12 : t             
     4 : 2016-02-01 00:00:00    1000     3795       0 :      281.64      290.64      296.63 : t             
     5 : 2016-03-01 00:00:00     975     3795       0 :      285.34      293.21      299.40 : t             
     6 : 2016-03-01 00:00:00    1000     3795       0 :      286.83      294.51      300.75 : t             
     7 : 2016-04-01 00:00:00     975     3795       0 :      287.85      297.03      303.41 : t             
     8 : 2016-04-01 00:00:00    1000     3795       0 :      289.42      298.57      304.99 : t             
     9 : 2016-05-01 00:00:00     975     3795       0 :      292.71      301.67      309.10 : t             
    10 : 2016-05-01 00:00:00    1000     3795       0 :      294.11      303.24      310.79 : t             
    11 : 2016-06-01 00:00:00     975     3795       0 :      295.53      302.51      310.17 : t             
    12 : 2016-06-01 00:00:00    1000     3795       0 :      296.83      304.01      311.66 : t             
    13 : 2016-07-01 00:00:00     975     3795       0 :      296.17      302.09      312.87 : t             
    14 : 2016-07-01 00:00:00    1000     3795       0 :      297.26      303.51      314.38 : t             
    15 : 2016-08-01 00:00:00     975     3795       0 :      296.01      300.90      309.52 : t             
    16 : 2016-08-01 00:00:00    1000     3795       0 :      297.21      302.34      311.00 : t             
    17 : 2016-09-01 00:00:00     975     3795       0 :      295.40      300.27      308.99 : t             
    18 : 2016-09-01 00:00:00    1000     3795       0 :      296.71      301.79      310.48 : t             
    19 : 2016-10-01 00:00:00     975     3795       0 :      285.79      297.38      303.29 : t             
    20 : 2016-10-01 00:00:00    1000     3795       0 :      288.00      298.78      304.88 : t             
    21 : 2016-11-01 00:00:00     975     3795       0 :      280.24      292.93      298.61 : t             
    22 : 2016-11-01 00:00:00    1000     3795       0 :      282.15      294.09      299.74 : t             
    23 : 2016-12-01 00:00:00     975     3795       0 :      278.99      291.18      296.56 : t             
    24 : 2016-12-01 00:00:00    1000     3795       0 :      281.15      292.30      298.00 : t
```

How I can get the level variable when using this command

```
cdo outputtab,date,lon,lat,value era_temperature_2016.nc > test_2016.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "lev" to take level data so it should be:

```
cdo outputtab,date,lon,lat,lev,value era_temperature_2016.nc > test_2016.csv
```

Also to obtain better csv output that splits columns by selected variables, you can use the following command:

```
cdo -outputtab,date,lon,lat,lev,value era_temperature_2016.nc | awk 'FNR==1{ row=$2","$3","$4","$5","$6;print row  } FNR!=1{ row=$1","$2","$3","$4","$5; print row}' > test_2016.csv
```